# How do i send push notifications to all of my devices using Cordova push plugin

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I have created an app using the cordova push plugin, however every time i want to send a push notification i have to get the registration id of that device and set it up in my APN for ios. Is there a way of saving the id automatically?
Here is my code for the apn node server :

```
 var apn = require('apn');

var options = { };

var token =  'Device Number';

var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

var myDevice = new apn.Device(token);

var message = new apn.Notification();

message.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1hour from now.
message.badge = 1;
message.sound = "ping.aiff";
message.alert = "\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 You have a new message";
message.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Caroline'};

//Potentially get rid of the notification in pushNotification
apnConnection.pushNotification(message, myDevice);\
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should save the registrations ids in some database, and send to all of them. You can't do a broadcast push "as is"

Comment: Okay thanks, could I save them all in an array? And if so how would i do that?